# Unicode Regular Expressions

Tags: c#, regex, unicode

I'm trying to handle the keys that are pressed from keyboard. So I made this Regex according to [Regex Unicode](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html):

```
private void tbName_KeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!Regex.IsMatch(e.Key.ToString(), @"^[\p{L}\p{Z}]$"))
    {
       e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

The problem is that it's only accepting letters, but white spaces (\p{Z}) not, and it should accept.

Btw, I tried \s (as usual), tried to put an "or" ( | ) between the 2 unicodes, but no way. It definitively don't want to work.

**EDIT 1:**

I tested char.IsLetter, but it allows a lot of non-letters like: [ []^~´`ªº ] and all numbers of lateral numeric keyboard of notebook, for example, while Unicode Regex do not. So I want a solution with Regex.

Comment: You do not need regex, just check with `if (!Char.IsAlpha(e.Key)  && !Char.IsWhiteSpace(e.Key)`

Comment: Well, I appreciate your comment, but IsAlpha is not a valid method in class Char. I tested char.IsLetter, but it allows a lot of non-letters like: [ []^~´`ªº ] and all numbers of lateral numeric keyboard of notebook, for example, while Unicode Regex do not.

Comment: I think I wanted to suggest `Char.IsLetter`, no idea why `IsAlpha` slipped through. BTW, `\s` is a valid shorthand character class to match Unicode whitespace.

Comment: No problem. It would be great if char.IsLetter accept only letters, as the Regex. Yes, I tried with \s as I mentioned in post, but it also doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not with your regex, but with `e.Key.ToString()`. `KeyRoutedEventArgs.Key` is a value of [the `VirtualKey` enum-type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.virtualkey.aspx), such as `Space` or `f5` or `H`. So your approach happens to work for letters — the name of the H key is `H` — but this is mostly a coincidence.

Using `e.Key` is fine, but you should examine the value either by comparing it to the enum constants, or by casting it to an `int` and looking at the numeric values (documented in the table above), or a mixture of these.

For example:

```
private void tbName_KeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == VirtualKey.Space) {
        // ignore spaces
    } else if ((int)e.Key >= (int)VirtualKey.A && (int)e.Key <= (int)VirtualKey.Z) {
        // ignore letters
    } else {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, dude. Btw it also accepts special characters like "é,á", it's nice, it was exactly what I was looking for

Comment: Hey, can you help me with more one thing? How to disable "Paste" into textbox? It's allowed to copy numbers into textbox :/

Comment: @developer033: In that case, you might try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask.